# Ubuntu font in Google's services

Tags: google-plus, google-docs, google

When I create documents in Google Docs, I can choose from several fonts. Is it possible to change that? Is it possible that the fonts like *Ubuntu* and *Purisa* to be used in Google's services, such as Google Docs or Google+?

Comment: Related: [Can I install custom fonts in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40575/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ubuntu` font is already available in Google Docs. And no, there is no way to add more fonts there.